# Convert void** pointer to equivalent Java type

Tags: java, pointers, dll, types

I'm loading a C DLL from a program written in Java.
I want to be able to call one of the methods from the DLL with this declaration :

```
dll_function(const char* foo1, const char* foo2, const char* foo3, void** bar, size_t* bar2);
```

**How do I call this method with arguments of correct type in Java ?** I know (theorically) how to call it, but what I would like to know is how to pass the "void**" and "size_t*" from my Java program ? Basically, **I want to know what the "equivalent type" for void** and size_t*** is **in Java**...

I found the Pointer class but didn't manage to get it work ?
Many thanks :)

Comment: You don't.  The concepts are not mappable.  You have to understand how the values will be used and "cheat".  Or write a C wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

I worked on a Java/JNI/C project several years ago, and we had to maintain opaque C pointers within Java objects. We used `long` values on the Java side to hold the C pointers, which were converted on the JNI side from `jlong` to `void*` or whatever pointer type we needed.

Since the Java `long` type is 64 bits wide, and JNI/C pointers are typically either 32 bits or 64 bits wide, we did not have any problems converting between them.

Answer (score 1):

The `size_t` is an integer used for the size of a variable in memory; as such you should be safe using `unsigned long` in Java.

The `void*` is likely a pointer to an object of unknown type. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043034/what-does-void-mean-in-c-c-and-c), is quite interesting on the matter. In Java `Object` is typically used in this case, but I do not know how you would convert between them, though [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152747/jni-not-support-types-as-void-unsigned-int-what-to-do) might help there.

Comment: Ah, good point. In that case, `long` in 32-bit code (as it is a 64-bit signed integer), or `BigInteger` in 64-bit code. Thinking on it, so log as you don't actually do anything with it in the Java code you may be able to get away with just a long for 64-bit addressing too, so long as the conversion between Java and the native language doesn't mangle it and can reinterpret the binary as though it were a size_t.

Comment: I read the JDK source code. `long` is used for storing "peer objects" in the JDK itself (search for `AWTObject` and look for the `pData` pointer if you are interested). Android source also uses `long` for the same purpose. So I think using `long` is the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your solutions but I guess I did not really understand correctly...
**But I solved my problem using this :**

```
import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;
```

I called the C function like that in my Java Program :

```
IntByReference myVoidPointerPointer = new IntByReference();
myCLibrary.myCFunction(myVoidPointerPointer);
```

The C function "myCFunction" looks like this :

```
void myCFunction(void** parameter);
```

Is it OK to do that ? It's working, but I was wondering if it's a correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the same...
a "new" is equivalent to an alloc and return a pointer to a memory zone.
So here you just pass the pointer to the memory zone.

What you want is to pass the pointer to the pointer zone.
I don't thing the equivalent exists in Java.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).